# SQL Query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these four tables:

```
SELECT [B_Key]
  ,[B_FiscalYear]
  ,[B_OrgCode]
  ,[B_SubObject]
  ,[B_Explanation]
  ,[B_CIPrefNo]
  ,[B_OrgBudgetAmt]
  ,[B_BudgetAmt]
  ,[B_Initials]
FROM [NAOLI].[dbo].[BudgetTbl]

SELECT [F_Fykey]
  ,[F_FiscalYear]
  ,[F_Year]
FROM [NAOLI].[dbo].[codeFiscalYearTbl]

SELECT [O_OrgKey]
  ,[O_OrgCode]
  ,[O_OrgDesc]
  ,[O_Divisions]
FROM [NAOLI].[dbo].[codeOrgCodeTbl]

SELECT [S_SubKey]
  ,[S_SubObject]
  ,[S_SubDescrip]
FROM [NAOLI].[dbo].[codeSubObjectTbl]
```

I need to combine different pieces of the information in these tables in order to make the table of information below:

```
   [B_FiscalYear]
  ,[O_OrgCode]
  ,[O_OrgDesc]
  ,[S_SubObject]
  ,[S_SubDescrip]
  ,[B_BudgetAmt]
  ,[B_Initials]
  ,[B_CIPrefNo]
  ,[B_OrgBudgetAmt]
```

I tried the below query but it returns 0 of the 20750 records.. How do I accomplish this? thanks

```
SELECT [B_FiscalYear]
  ,[B_OrgCode]
  ,[O_OrgDesc]
  ,[B_SubObject]
  ,[S_SubDescrip]
  ,[B_BudgetAmt]
  ,[B_Initials]
  ,[B_CIPrefNo]
  ,[B_OrgBudgetAmt]

INTO dbo.BudgetsTbl
  FROM [BudgetTbl] BT, [codeFiscalYearTbl] FY, [codeOrgCodeTbl] OC, [codeSubObjectTbl] SO
WHERE BT.B_FiscalYear = FY.F_Year and BT.B_OrgCode = OC.O_OrgCode and BT.B_SubObject = SO.S_SubObject
```

Comment: Without knowing what the data looks like this will be a hard problem to solve. I would suggest selecting data from one table (start with BudgetTbl), then adding one joined table at a time to the results until you find out which join constraint is causing the omission of data. Make sure you're choosing the appropriate join methods as well (left, right, etc.).

Comment: Apart from using implicit `JOIN`s (you should use proper explicit `JOIN`s), your query should be fine. Are you sure that you can join those tables on those columns?

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you execute the query? Or does it just report "0 rows affected"? (depending in which flavour of SQL database you are using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper join syntax is:

```
SELECT [B_FiscalYear], [B_OrgCode], [O_OrgDesc], [B_SubObject], [S_SubDescrip],
       [B_BudgetAmt], [B_Initials], [B_CIPrefNo], [B_OrgBudgetAmt]
INTO dbo.BudgetsTbl
FROM BudgetTbl BT join
     codeFiscalYearTbl FY
     on BT.B_FiscalYear = FY.F_Year  join
     codeOrgCodeTbl OC
     on BT.B_OrgCode = OC.O_OrgCode join
     codeSubObjectTbl SO
     on BT.B_SubObject = SO.S_SubObject
```

Presumably, one or more of your lookup tables are empty.  If you want all rows, replace the "join" with "left outer join" in the above query.

Comment: Thanks so much! needed the left outer join worked like a charmed, I'll mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The join should be like this:

```
SELECT [B_FiscalYear]
  ,[B_OrgCode]
  ,[O_OrgDesc]
  ,[B_SubObject]
  ,[S_SubDescrip]
  ,[B_BudgetAmt]
  ,[B_Initials]
  ,[B_CIPrefNo]
  ,[B_OrgBudgetAmt]
FROM BudgetTbl BT
JOIN codeFiscalYearTbl FY ON BT.B_FiscalYear = FY.F_Year
JOIN codeOrgCodeTbl OC ON BT.B_OrgCode = OC.O_OrgCode
JOIN codeSubObjectTbl SO ON BT.B_SubObject = SO.S_SubObject
```

You can look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ff6b/7 for more info.
Also you can add left joins if needed.